# Always have to "clean and build" to see my changes in my Angular/Spring project

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem on my AngularJS project, I'm using the [SB Admin Angular](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/) template, but I really don't know how any changes I make on the code I need to clean and build the project to I see it, but it just happen when running on a server, stand alone it not show.

Answer (score 0):

Try start the app with

```
grunt serve
```

grunt sevre:dist is for the builded minified version the default serve works fine with just a browser refresh

Comment: not sure about it, I'm not using grunt on the project no more, I'm using the template on a Spring application now.

Comment: How do you deploy your spring app? Package a WAR?

Comment: I run inside the Netbeans, but even opening the index from apache I have the same behavior, because of it I believe is something in the angular configuration or something?

Comment: don't think so. I don't really know how netbeans deploy the app for dev. Maybe netbeans create a target dist for the runtime and that's why you don't see the changes. just supposing never worked with netbeans sry

Comment: Thank your time anyway, I appreciate it.